# Getting an out-of-bounds error on string->char conversion despite being in-bounds

Tags: java, android

EDIT: So, I've sort of fixed it for now. Just added a input length validation and it works fine. Doing it like this:

```
if(input.length() != 0){
}
```

I've got this method that takes in a string, splits the string, converts the first letter to a char and then evaluates whether it is a letter or a number. tokens[] is at 1 instead of 0 because the string I'm taking in has a space and when I debug, something like "bench" becomes "", "b", "e", "n", "c", "h". It's weird because when I debug and step through the method everything works fine. Why am I getting this error?

When the string is "Dead-Lift"

```
// comments are exactly what debug gives me
boolean isExerciseName(String input) { // input: "Dead-Lift"
    String[] tokens = input.split(""); // tokens: {"", "D", "e", "a", "d", + 5 more}

    boolean isExercise = true; // isExercise: true

     char c = tokens[1].charAt(0); // c: 'D' 68
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) { // c:'D' 68
        isExercise = false;
    }

    return isExercise;

}
```

So obviously I'm not out of bounds, because c becomes 'D' just like it should.

The error specifically is:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

toCharArray does seem like the better idea, so here it is in that form:

```
boolean isExerciseName(String input) {
    char[] tokens = input.toCharArray(); // tokens: {D, e, a, d, etc}

    boolean isExercise = true;

    char c = tokens[0]; // c: 'D' also, this is the line that errors out
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        isExercise = false;
    }

    return isExercise;

}
```

And I still get the error

I also get the error where I call the method:

```
if(isExerciseName(itemString) && !itemKey.equals("private_journal)){
```

Now, the odd thing that I've just noticed is that if I let the program "wait" when I debug and ignore the error message, it works out fine. The input I'm getting is coming from my Firebase database, so maybe this method is being called before it gets that data? And thus is trying to call the method on a null value?

Comment: Your splitting your input with empty string, so of course it does not split anything and your tokens var it will be a Array of String of length 1, meanwhile you're asking to retrive tokes[1]. Anywat toCharArray is the way http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: @AntonioCalì I thought that split("") would just split the word into letters? Debug shows that that's happening correctly.

Comment: Instead of using split you can simply use input.toCharArray () and then check the first character

Comment: So when exception is raised?

Comment: Why not accessing the first character directly with input.charAt(0)?

Comment: Check edit guys. Also tried input.charAt(0) with the same error occuring

Comment: Could be possible exception is raised somewhere else but not in this method?

Comment: The error also occurs (at the same time) at the place I call the method. I'll edit it into the main post

Comment: Impossible about the null value, because it will raise a NullPointerException instead an outofbounds

Comment: Error is because of this: String[] tokens = input.split("");   You are specifying "" for the split which means your String array will only have as value: Dead-Lift, so when you do "tokens[1].charAt(0);" it throws the exception as tokens[1] doesn't exist, only tokens[0].

Comment: @ScottS, but now I'm using input.charAt(0) and am getting the same error?

Comment: Why not use for loop to go iterate over the string's characters and as you iterate the string you can add the single characters to your character array?

Comment: Because I only need the first letter...None of my inputs that are exercise names will start with a number, that's just how I'm doing my validation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it using this:

```
if(input.length() != 0)
```

before going into the charAt structure